# Effect of reshaping an numpy array from (2,) to (2,1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math

I was trying to calculate a covariance matrix of 2 arrays `a` and `b` via a dot product in python with the formula `a @ b.T`.

The initial form of my input arrays are `(2,)` when the shape is printed. Obviously the result of this calculation is a single scalar but not the covariance matrix i need.
As it turns out i needed to reshape the arrays(i.e. `a.reshape(2,1)`) to a receive the desired `(2,2)` covariance matrix.

Now my problem is that i dont understand what effect the reshaping of the arrays has on the data, more specifically why i am allowed to do it and receive the result i want.
How come i can just reshape the array to receive the covariance matrix, what is the thought process behind it?
I do understand the how the dot product works, but as i said i dont get why i am allowed to just reshape the array to receive the desired outcome dimensions.

I hope i made my problem understandable, i have  a bit of trouble formulating it.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: have you read the docs of `np.matmul`?  Pay attention to how it handles 1d vs 2d arrays.  `np.dot` does the same thing, though the wording is a bit different,

Comment: Also look at `b.T` for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `reshape` doesn't change the values of an array, it does affect how the array interacts with other arrays.  Operators like `*` and `@` have their rules about handling arrays with various shapes.

```
In [221]: a, b = np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4])
In [222]: a,b
Out[222]: (array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]))
```

`transpose` of a 1d array changes nothing.  It does not 'add' a dimension; it just reverses the existing dimensions:

```
In [223]: b.T
Out[223]: array([3, 4])
```

For 1d arrays, `matmul` and `dot` do the 'scalar', or 'dot' product.  That's clearly documented:

```
In [224]: a@(b.T)
Out[224]: 11
```

Reshaping the arrays to `(2,1)`.  Now transpose does make a difference:

```
In [225]: a[:,None]
Out[225]: 
array([[1],
       [2]])
In [226]: b[:,None].T
Out[226]: array([[3, 4]])
```

Here we have a (2,1) with (1,2), which does the matrix product, summing on the size 1 dimensions.  The result is (2,2).  Again clearly documented.

```
In [227]: a[:,None]@b[:,None].T
Out[227]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

Other ways of getting that product:

```
In [228]: np.outer(a,b)
Out[228]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
In [229]: a[:,None]*b
Out[229]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

The last case does elementwise multiplication of (2,1) with a (2,).  The rules of `broadcasting` apply.  Read up on that!

Comment: But where does the one Dimension come from when reshaping? It seems like like reshaping from `(2,)` to `(2,1)` "adds" a dimension, without subtracting a dimension anywhere.

Comment: As long as the total number of elements doesn't change, you can reshape many ways.  `a1=a.reshape(1,2,1,1)` is legit.